# ReSharper - Resolving Razor views in separate assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, resharper, resharper-6.0

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 solution where some Views (and Controllers) are located in separate assembly (later on they are loaded via MEF). This separate assembly is a Class Library project (a .dll) and the ReSharper can't resolve the Views from inside the controller (even if the View exists it shows it with Red color inside the Controller).

Any ideas?

I am using Build 6.0.2202.688 on 2011-06-29T18:14:16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2011/01/20/how-to-get-razor-intellisense-for-model-in-a-class-library-project.aspx) post it seems that everything work fine now. *(The problem doesn't seem to be related with ReSharper.)*

Answer (score 0):

Views project must reference controllers project.

Comment: Views and Controllers are on same project but not a web project - a .dll instead (which we then load via mef into main web project).

Comment: You mean you have third project which references two others, one with views, another with controllers? Anyway, views project must reference controllers' one - then ReSharper will resolve view references.

Comment: Everything is inside a .dll (together with Views and Controllers).